# ld: cannot find -lc when linking as elf i386

Tags: ld

I'm stumped on this.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I want link together an executable as a 32-bit program, for educational purposes.

My ld default search paths are all for the 64bit toolchain, so I think I need to invoke ld with additional library search paths since I want to link as 32bit. It can not find libc for some reason.

```
 ld -mi386linux -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ -lc -o cc codechef.o -dynamic-linker /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
```

This gives me the error `ld: cannot find -lc`

I have verified that libc.so.6 file does exist at /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

adding --verbose to my command reveals: attempt to open /lib/i386-linux-gnu//libc.a failed Why does my ubuntu installation not have this file but does have the .so?

Comment: adding --verbose to my command reveals:

attempt to open /lib/i386-linux-gnu//libc.a failed

Why does my ubuntu installation not have this file but does have the .so?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the information in the comment.

Comment: As for your problem, why don't use use the GCC front-end program `gcc` for both compilation and linking? If you add the `gcc` option `-m32` it should automatically use the correct files and libraries for a 32-bit executable.

Comment: Since this is mostly for me messing around with ld and asm for learning purposes, every problem I run into, I try to solve to completion (opposed to finding a workaround)

Comment: You could always use `gcc -v` for a verbose output of what `gcc` is really doing, what programs it executes and the flags it passes.